# How to save a Quora page as is, to be read offline?

Tags: download, quora

I am trying to download a Quora page for offline reading, and I can't seem to get it right for this supposedly simple task.

For reference, the page I'm trying to download is [this one](https://www.quora.com/What-was-the-biggest-design-flaw-to-ever-occur-in-history-How-was-it-fixed-if-it-was/answer/Jeremy-Hughes-75)

I am using Chrome, and these are the things I have tried:

1. Save the page from Chrome. This will save the page in a two-part files: one the HTML and a folder for the assets. *Problem*: When I opened the saved page, I can see the content for a bit, but then it tries to make a network connection, and it doesn't work because it uses relative path, and it triggers my browser opening this to try to reach the server "home" (my home directory). Loading the page with JavaScript disabled will just show the no-script text.
2. Use save as PDF. This will print the content into a PDF. This is quite good, and very close to what I would like to achieve, if not for the sticky Quora banner covering the top of every page, covering some of the content that I would like to see.
3. Save as image (using GoFullPage extension). This also works, but I lost information of all the image links.

Ideally, what I want is to save the current HTML/DOM state, and not modify it (I don't need the videos to work, I just want to be able to read). Saving the page seems to save the content as well (I can see it in the downloaded HTML file), but the JavaScript reloads seems to be on the way.

Is there a good way to save this Quora page to be read offline at later time?

Comment: Have you tried using [Pocket](https://getpocket.com/)?

Comment: @adiga: Does that work to save the content for offline as well? When I click on "Save to Pocket", on my Pocket list I just see a redirect link, not the page.

Comment: It takes some time to download and it will update with proper title of the article. Pocket sometimes ignores images and videos. So, I'm not sure if it is what you're looking for. Did it work?